# Writing cleaner PHP code to add additional options

Tags: php, form, ajax

I have a contact form that will perform validation on the server. Right now the form checks if the fields are empty or not. My goal is to expand it following:

Check the fields for particular format, if it is a proper email format, phone number format, etc
Set the field as required or not

My form is as below, I appreciate any suggestions on how to clean it up and make it easier to adjust and overall cleaner.

```
<?php

ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "php-error.log");
error_log( "Errors" );

include "recaptcha.php";
include 'email.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';

$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();         // array to pass back data

// validate the variables ======================================================
    // if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array

    if (empty($_POST['firstName']))
        $errors['firstName'] = 'First Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['lastName']))
        $errors['lastName'] = 'Last Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['companyName']))
        $errors['companyName'] = 'Company Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['companyAddress']))
        $errors['companyAddress'] = 'Company Address is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['city']))
        $errors['city'] = 'City is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['state']))
        $errors['state'] = 'State is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['emailAddress']))
        $errors['emailAddress'] = 'Email Address is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['comment']))
        $errors['comment'] = 'Comment is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
        $errors['recaptcha'] = 'Captcha is required.';


// return a response ===========================================================

    // Check ReCaptcha Validation

    if(!validateRecaptcha($secret, $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]))
    {
        $errors['recaptcha'] = 'Captcha is required.';
    }

    if ( ! empty($errors)) {

        // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } else {

        // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

        // DO ALL YOUR FORM PROCESSING HERE
        // THIS CAN BE WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO (LOGIN, SAVE, UPDATE, WHATEVER)

        // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    }

    // return all our data to an AJAX call
    echo json_encode($data);

//Begin of send email
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Enable SMTP debugging.
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();
//Set SMTP host name
$mail->Host = "smtp.server.com";
//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Provide username and password
$mail->Username = "user@server.com";
$mail->Password = "super_secret_password";
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
//Set TCP port to connect to
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = $emailAddress;

$mail->addAddress("name@server.com", "Recepient Name");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = $emailBody;

if(!$mail->send())
{
  $data['success'] = false;
  $data['errors']  =  "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### General inconsistency

Basically your code is borderline off topic. Although it could work, it is not a working code in the sense a programmer could take it; but rather a set of copy-pasted code blocks loosely (and wrongly) connected to each other.

The main problem is inconsistent code structure. You have `$data['success']` set at the end of the script but... it goes nowhere.

So it basically should be

```
if ($errors) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    // the rest or phpmailer code goes on
    if(!$mail->send())
    {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  =  ["Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo];
    }
    else
    {
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    }
}
// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
```

Note that another error has been fixed. $data['errors'] should be an array, but in case of phpmailer error you were sending a string.

#### Configuration options

```
error_log( "Errors" );
```

Always use the [**absolute filesystem path**](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths#absolute) to a log file or you'll end up with log files in the every directory.

Also, it's better to configure such settings on the [server level](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#tldr), for some errors may occur before the file gets parsed completely. Or at least put these settings into a configuration file and include it in all your php scripts.

#### Autoload

Instead of requiring files manually, consider using [PSR-4 autoload](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and Composer. It's really easy, you just have to install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/), then run two commands in console

```
php composer.phar require google/recaptcha
php composer.phar require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

and then add just a single require line into your code

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

and all classes will be loaded automatically!

#### Validation and sanitization

You may want to verify whether the email address is valid.

```
if (empty($_POST['emailAddress'])) {
    $errors['emailAddress'] = 'Email Address is required.';
} else {
    $emailAddress = filter_var($errors['emailAddress'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($emailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors['emailAddress'] = 'Email Address is invalid.';
    }
}
```

and also sanitize the email body,

```
$emailBody = htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']);
```